# Pointer to a object class throwing "does not name a type"

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I have a hardware class having a pointer to a TLB class object, and initialising that in the constructor. However, Codeblocks (GNU GCC) is giving me the error
"proj3_hardware.h|15|error: 'TLB' does not name a type"
"proj3_hardware.h|15|error: expected ';' before '*' token"

I just cannot see where is the error in the code. Thank you.

proj3_hardware.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "proj3_globals.h"
#include "proj3_pagetable.h"
#include "proj3_tlb.h"

class Hardware{

public:

    // Defines the hardware parts
    int global_simulation_time;
    TLB* tlb;
    PageManagement* pagemm;

    // Hardware constructor and methods
    Hardware(int pageTableType, int replacementAlgo);

    void execute();
    void diskaccess();

};
```

proj3_tlb.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "proj3_globals.h"

// Assumes that the TLB is using LRU

class TLBEntry{

    public:

        char validEntry;
        int VirtualAddress;
        int PhysicalAddress;
        long LastUsed;
};

class TLB{

    private:

        TLBEntry entries[HARDWARE_TLBSIZE];
        int* simulation_time;

    public:

        TLB(int* simulation_time);

        void tlb_add(int virtualaddress, int physicaladdress);
        int tlb_lookup(int virtualaddress);
        void tlb_flush();

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiles for me.

The error must be in other code; Check your other header files for:

- any suspicious `#define`s
- missing semicolons?
- wrong include guards (this one is my best guess)

Comment: You got it... the header guard was the problem.